# Excel VBA import json file

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to import this json file:

{"status": "ok", "results_time": "0.6989 sec.", "results_count": 1, "results": [{"date": "2017-12-01", "site_url": "digitment.com.hk", "site_title": "seo company hong kong | search engine optimization services asia", "site_description": "help your business grow with help from first page, one of hong kong\u2019s most experienced seo & digital marketing firms. enquire today!", "audience": {"visits": 2471, "time_on_site_avg": "00:01:24", "page_views_avg": 2.262725673935643, "bounce_rate": 54.94}, "traffic": {"value": 2471, "percent": 100, "countries": [{"country": "Hong Kong", "value": 1850, "percent": 74.87}, {"country": "India", "value": 252, "percent": 10.24}, {"country": "Taiwan", "value": 115, "percent": 4.66}, {"country": "Sweden", "value": 107, "percent": 4.35}, {"country": "Malaysia", "value": 80, "percent": 3.24}, {"country": "Other", "value": 6523, "percent": 2.64}], "sources": {"direct": {"value": 586, "percent": 23.74}, "search_organic": {"value": 1024, "percent": 41.44, "top_keywords": [{"keyword": "first page hk", "value": 430, "percent": 42.05}, {"keyword": "google \u8cfc\u7269", "value": 205, "percent": 20.08}, {"keyword": "seo", "value": 195, "percent": 19.06}, {"keyword": "firstpage", "value": 71, "percent": 7.01}, {"keyword": "\u9999\u6e2fseo\u516c\u53f8", "value": 71, "percent": 7.01}]}, "search_ad": {"value": 793, "percent": 32.09, "top_keywords": [{"keyword": "facebook \u5ee3\u544a\u6536\u8cbb", "value": 279, "percent": 35.29}, {"keyword": "seo", "value": 279, "percent": 35.29}, {"keyword": "google adwords", "value": 46, "percent": 5.88}, {"keyword": "facebook \u4ed8\u9322\u5ee3\u544a", "value": 46, "percent": 5.88}, {"keyword": "facebook \u5ee3\u544a", "value": 46, "percent": 5.88}]}, "referral": {"value": 0, "percent": 0, "top_referrals": []}, "referral_ad": {"value": 36, "percent": 1.46, "top_referrals": [{"site": "hk.entertainment.appledaily.com", "value": 36, "percent": 100}]}, "social": {"value": 29, "percent": 1.18, "top_socials": [{"site": "Facebook", "value": 29, "percent": 100}]}, "appstore": {"value": 0, "percent": 0, "top_apps": []}, "mail": {"value": 0, "percent": 0}}, "estimated": {"2017-07-01": 7634, "2017-08-01": 27912, "2017-09-01": 52102, "2017-10-01": 2449, "2017-11-01": 1964, "2017-12-01": 2471}}}]}

```
Dim Item As Dictionary
Dim Item2 As Dictionary
Dim Item3 As Dictionary
Dim jsonObject As Object
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("dict.competitor", ForReading)
jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close
Set jsonObject = ParseJson(jsonText)

For Each Item In jsonObject("results")
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = Item("date")
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value = Item("site_url")
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = Item("site_title")
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 4).Value = Item("site_description")
    Sheets(1).Cells(5, 2).Value = Item("audience")("visits")
    Sheets(1).Cells(6, 2).Value = Item("audience")("time_on_site_avg")
    Sheets(1).Cells(7, 2).Value = Item("audience")("page_views_avg")
    Sheets(1).Cells(8, 2).Value = Item("audience")("bounce_rate")

    aa = 12
    For Each Item2 In Item("traffic")("countries")
            Sheets(1).Cells(aa, 3).Value = Item2("country")
            Sheets(1).Cells(aa, 4).Value = Item2("value")
            Sheets(1).Cells(aa, 5).Value = Item2("percent")
            aa = aa + 1

    Next

    For Each Item3 In Item("traffic")("sources")
             MsgBox ("OK")
    Next

Next
```

Error occurs when importing Item("traffic")("sources").

How can I import this nested format correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing some code to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link out
 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30B14928-5550-41F5-97CA-7A3E9C363ED7 
it uses a function named Delimiter 
step1) Click Data >Text to Columns.
step2) start the Convert Text to Columns Wizard. Click Delimited > Next.
step3) Check Space, and clear the rest of the boxes, or check Comma and Space if that is how your text is split (Smith, John, with a comma and space between the names). You can see a preview of your data in the Data preview window.

Hope it helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18561911)

Comment: Thanks, i have include the essential part of the answer :)